# On Linux, is it possible to do a one-off login as another user, overriding their default shell?

Tags: linux, login

As root I would like to login as a service user (jenkins - the CI server) and manipulate files with its user,group and umask settings.

Normally I would (as root) do `sudo -i -u jenkins`, or even `su - jenkins`. However jenkins' default shell is /bin/false, which exits immediately.

Is there a way to login as Jenkins but specify a different shell to use? Do I really have to change jenkins' shell in `/etc/passwd/`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

su on linux supports setting the shell with the `--shell` option

```
su jenkins --shell=/bin/bash
```

You will need to su as root for this to work. From the man page:

```
       If the target user has a restricted shell (i.e. the shell field of
       this users entry in /etc/passwd is not listed in /etc/shell), then
       the --shell option or the $SHELL environment variable wont be taken
       into account, unless su is called by root.
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you read the manual page (or `--help` output) to the `su` command?

```
su -s /bin/bash -
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:
`su - jenkins -c /bin/bash`

or

`sudo -u jenkins /bin/bash`